# How do i color a date in PyQt4 calendar widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, calendar, pyqt4

I want to paint date when  i clicking on it.
This is the code:
date - an object that i want to paint.
Hope for help...

```
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):   
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        cal = QtGui.QCalendarWidget(self)
        cal.setGridVisible(True)
        cal.clicked[QtCore.QDate].connect(self.showDate)
        self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        date = cal.selectedDate()
        self.lbl.setText(date.toString())
        self.lbl.move(130, 150)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Calendar')
        self.resize(500,400)    
        self.show()

    def showDate(self, date):     
        self.lbl.setText(date.toString())
        print date
        print str(date.day()) + "/" + str(date.month()) + "/" + str(date.year()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here, but since I'm hacking away at the tutorial on PyQt4 from zetcode.com myself, I thought I might throw in a few suggestions.

You can change the font color of `lbl` by adding a stylesheet. If you click on a date in the calendar, the printed label will turn green:

```
def showDate(self, date):
    self.label.setText(date.toString())
    self.label.setStyleSheet('color: green')
```

If you want to color the background of your label, go about it this way:

```
def showDate(self, date):
    self.label.setText(date.toString())
    self.label.setStyleSheet('background-color: red')
```

---

It just occurred to me that you might mean *print* instead of *paint*. So here's a way to print the date in your style format:

```
# in your initUI method:
    self.dateLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self)
    date = cal.selectedDate()
    self.dateLabel.setText("{}/{}/{}".format(date.day(),
        date.month(), date.year())) # output: 20/9/2013

# change your showDate method to this:
def showDate(self, date):

    myDateFormat = "{}/{}/{}".format(date.day(), date.month(),
        date.year())
    self.dateLabel.setText(myDateFormat) # output: 1/1/2013
    self.dateLabel.adjustSize()
```